# How can I have a similar slider to the one as this website

Tags: slider, slideshow

Does anyone know if there is a jquery library to have a slider to the one shown at the bottom of [https://district2.studio](https://district2.studio/)?

It's vertical, works with the vertical scroll and when the slide changes, the previous one barely moves, and the new one has a minimal ken burns effect while sliding over.

I imagine it's necessary to combine a library with custom javascript or css.